# How to Change the Format of a DateTimeField Object when it is Displayed in HTML through Ajax?

Tags: python, django, ajax, datetime

**models.py**

```
class Log(models.Model):
    source = models.CharField(max_length=1000, default='')
    date = models.DateTimeField(default=datetime.now, blank = True)
```

**views.py**

The objects in the Log model are filtered so that only those with source names that match a specific account name are considered. The values of these valid objects will then be listed and returned using a JsonResponse.

```
def backlog_list(request): 
    account_name = request.POST['account_name']
    access_log = Log.objects.filter(source=account_name)
    return JsonResponse({"access_log":list(access_log.values())})
```

**dashboard.html**

This Ajax script is the one that brings back the account name to the views.py. If there are no valid objects, the HTML will be empty; however, it will display it like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JVlQ2.png) otherwise.

```
<h3>You scanned the QR code during these times.</h3>
<div id="display">
    
</div>

<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
    
    setInterval(function(){
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url : "/backlog_list",
            data:{
                  account_name:$('#account_name').val(),
                  csrfmiddlewaretoken:$('input[name=csrfmiddlewaretoken]').val(),
                },
            success: function(response){
                console.log(response);
                $("#display").empty();
                for (var key in response.access_log)
                {
                    var temp="<div class='container darker'><span class='time-left'>"+response.access_log[key].date+"</span></div>";
                    $("#display").append(temp);
                }
            },
            error: function(response){
                alert('An error occurred')
            }
        });
    },1000);
    })
</script>
```

My goal is to have the Date and time displayed like "Jan. 10, 2000, 9:30:20 A.M."

I've tried changing the format directly from the models.py by adding "strftime" but the error response is triggered.

Answer (score 0):

One way to set the format you need is via Javascript, Tharun posted an example in his answer.

Alternatively, you can specify the format you need in `views.py`:

```
def backlog_list(request): 
    ...
    dates = [
        val.strftime('%b. %d, %Y, %I:%M:%S %p') 
        for val in access_log.values_list("date", flat=True)
    ]
    return JsonResponse({"access_log":[{"date": d} for d in dates]})
```

Format string reference - https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-format-codes

Comment: I tried this and it works but it only shows 1 object out of the 2 that is valid. The one that it shows is the most recent object. Also, I can't seem to understand where the "d" in "d for d in dates" came from. Is it a shortcut for something?

Comment: I had a typo in the code - closing curly brace was in the wrong place. That must had been a reason for you seeing only 1 of 2 objects. `d for d in dates` - this is a shortcut syntax for creating a list out of some iterable, it is called "list comprehension" - https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions